# Will Distant Spell Link work via Improved Share Spells

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

[Distant spell Link](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/distant-spell-link) lets you use your companions Share Spells feature at close range, rather then touch.

> Benefit(s): The range of your allied creature's share spells ability increases to close (25 feet + 5 feet for every 2 levels) as long as you have line of effect to the creature when you cast the shared spell. If your allied creature has the deliver touch spells ability, you can designate your allied creature as the spell's source when you cast a touch spell as long as you are within close range of it. The creature must still deliver the touch spell at its touch range.

[Improved Spell-Sharing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-spell-sharing-teamwork) lets you split the duration of any spell you cast between you and your companion with only 1 cast.

> Benefit: When you are adjacent to or sharing a square with your companion creature and that companion creature has this feat, you can cast a spell on yourself and divide the duration evenly between yourself and the companion creature. You can use this feat only on spells with a duration of at least 2 rounds. For example, you could cast bull's strength on yourself, and instead of the spell lasting 1 minute per level on yourself, it lasts 5 rounds per level on yourself and 5 rounds per level on your companion.

Because Distant Spell Link removed the need for you to be adjacent to your companion for the purposes of Spell-Sharing, would you need to still be adjacent to take advantage of the improved feat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Adjacency or square-sharing remains necessary when using the feat [Improved Spell-sharing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-spell-sharing-teamwork) even if the caster has the feat [Distant Spell Link](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/distant-spell-link)

The feat [Distant Spell Link](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/distant-spell-link) affects how the special ability share spells (e.g. [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons#TOC-Share-Spells-Ex-)) works, but the feat [Improved Spell-sharing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-spell-sharing-teamwork) does *not*, failing to mention the special ability share spells in its mechanics at all, the feat essentially giving the creature a brand new special ability.

Yes, that kind of sucks and a GM *could* make a house rule to remedy this, but the ability of a caster's spells to do double duty *via* the feat Improved Spell-sharing is *already* pretty awesome, so it wouldn't surprise me if a careful GM *won't* make such a house rule, therefore forcing the caster to spend a round or two simultaneously buffing himself and his familiar before unleashing the familiar and wading into battle himself.